# Is it possible to extend a Java class with one having the same name

Tags: java

I'm working with a ridiculously large codebase and need to move a file from one package to another. However, I do not have the whole codebase locally, so I am not sure if I have found and updated every reference to the original file. In order to ensure that I don't break anything, I would like to leave the original file, and simply have it extend the new file that I created. Ideally, they'd both have the exact same name. Overtime, I plan to deprecate and remove the old file, but for now this seems like the most robust solution. However, I cannot figure out how to get it to work in Java.

Here is the new class:

```
package myproject.util.http;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public abstract class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    public void service (HttpServletRequest  request,
                         HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // implementation of service
    }

}
```

Here is the old class that extends the new:

```
package myproject.util.net;

import myproject.util.http.MyServlet;

public abstract class MyServlet extends myproject.util.http.MyServlet
{
// this class was deprecated, use myproject.util.http.MyServlet instead
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
MyServlet is already defined in this compilation unit
```

Is this possible, or am I going to have to come up with a new name for the parent class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it but you need to remove the `import` statement.

Otherwise the compilation unit will import all the classes declared in your package to be used without the fully qualified name: this means that you wouldn't be able to distinguish between the two `MyServlet`, this is why it is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove import and have fully qualified name `myproject.util.http.MyServlet`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the import statement and all will be well.